# Android - Get "Source Not Found" Error after adding a custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a custom layout which is extended from Relative layout and put it into one of the activity. After that I got "Source Not Found" error. The code is very simple so I am not sure what the cause is and how to debug this error.

The code is as follow:

**CustomLayout.class**

```
public class CustomLayout extends RelativeLayout{

public CustomLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    this.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_layout, this);
}
```

**custom_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyActivityLayout.xml**

```
......
<com.example.view.CustomLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create another constructor having Context and AttributeSet as its parameters.

`public CommentBarLayout(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
}`

Answer (score 0):

First, please you have to used proper Constructor.

```
public  class CustomLayout extends RelativeLayout{
 public CustomLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    this.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_layout, this);
}
```

Then, if you have get problem post, where you have faced problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry that the name of constructor is just my mistake. In my project, it is same as the class name. It has been corrected here.

Comment: @yashodhan divakaran's solution solves the problem. Thank you.